# Pass array to listeners and get updated array

Tags: php, laravel, events, listener

I am passing an array to an event and I am updating the array in the listeners. But I am not getting back the updated array after the event.

This is where I am calling the event:

```
$roles_permissions = ["val1"];
event(new SeedingRolesPermissions($roles_permissions));
var_dump($roles_permissions);
```

This is the event class' code. I am simply using the constructor to set up the event's roles_permissions array. I tried passing array by reference as well but didn't help.

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SeedingRolesPermissions
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $roles_permissions;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($roles_permissions)
    {
        $this->roles_permissions = $roles_permissions;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

This is the listener to the event:

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Sales\Listeners;

use App\Events\SeedingRolesPermissions;
use Log;

class AddRolesPermissions
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        
    }

    
    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  SeedingRolesPermissions  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(SeedingRolesPermissions $event)
    {
        $event->roles_permissions[] =  ["val2"];
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: We need to know what event is. But ignoring this missing information, it is possible that the event object (`SeedingRolesPermissions`) is serialized in any way or cloned, so it is not the same object anymore.

Comment: its not the same array (they are copy on write)

Comment: I have updated the question and added complete code for the event and listener. Are you able to help out about passing array by reference and making sure the event object isn't cloned? Thanks for your help